# Mysql, filter out files that does not have an record in a second table

Tags: mysql, join, filter, subquery

This is my first post in here.
I have searched a few times and could not find topics that exactly cover my need.
English is not my main language, so it could very well be that i have not searched in the most optimal way to find what i am looking for.

I have an database from an commercial software. It stores information about files in a few different tables.
What we wish to do is to filter out all files that does not have an record in one of the tables.

Example:

Table "file" contains all information about a file
Table "path" contains all information about a path to a folder or a file
Table "spreadlink" contains all information about links between files.

I have created an query that works, but I find it very slow and my question is if it is possible to make it better in terms of speed?

I guess I could use `left join` and stuff like that in my query, but I am not that experienced in using the different joins.

Any suggestions on how to speed it up?

The query i have so far:

```
SELECT 
    f.FileID AS 'FileID', 
    CONCAT(p.path, '/', f.unixname) AS 'filepath', 
    k.Field7 as Keywords, 
    k.Field293 as Fakturerat, 
    f.UTF8Name as FileName, 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(f.CreateDate) AS 'CreateDate', 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(f.ModifyDate) AS 'ModifyDate', 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(f.AccessDate) AS 'AccessDate'
FROM 
    file AS f 
    JOIN path AS p ON (f.pathid=p.pathid)
    JOIN keyword1 AS k ON (f.fileid=k.fileid) 
WHERE 
    path LIKE '/My/path/to/folder/structure/%' 
    AND (f.fileid NOT IN (select TargetFileID from spreadlink )) 
    AND (f.fileid NOT IN (select FileID from spreadlink ));
```

`f.FileID`, `p.FileID`, `TargetFileID` and `FileID` from `spreadlink` are all fileID:s that identifies a file or folder and are the file identifiers in all tables.

*EDIT*: This is what mysqlslow log says about the query:

Query_time: 12.067222  Lock_time: 0.000078 Rows_sent: 4153  Rows_examined: 3628518

*EDIT:* here is explain result of my query

```
+----+--------------------+------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | type           | possible_keys     | key             | key_len | ref                | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | k          | ALL            | PRIMARY           | NULL            | NULL    | NULL               | 1441716 |                          | 
|  1 | PRIMARY            | f          | eq_ref         | PRIMARY,BY_PATHID | PRIMARY         | 4       | webnative.k.FileID |       1 | Using where              | 
|  1 | PRIMARY            | p          | eq_ref         | PRIMARY,BY_PATH   | PRIMARY         | 4       | webnative.f.PathID |       1 | Using where              | 
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | spreadlink | index_subquery | BY_FILEID         | BY_FILEID       | 8       | func               |      20 | Using index; Using where | 
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | spreadlink | index_subquery | BY_TARGETFILEID   | BY_TARGETFILEID | 8       | func               |      11 | Using index; Using where | 
+----+--------------------+------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------+
```

I found the reason in the end.
I had an "underscore" (_) in the path and according to mysql that is an wildcard, that slowed it down quite a lot. After i had placed an backslash () before the underscore sign, the query only took 1 second to complete.

Thanks for the help anyway in this matter.

Comment: Could you please post the results of `explain` of your query.

Comment: i have added "explain" results to my original post. I hope that is ok.

Comment: Rickard, could you post the `describe` of your `keyword1` table as well please?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using sqlfiddle.com so that we all can try your query out. Do you have index on your `path` field.  Please try the following and share your results:

```
SELECT 
    f.FileID AS 'FileID', 
    CONCAT(p.path, '/', f.unixname) AS 'filepath', 
    k.Field7 as Keywords, 
    k.Field293 as Fakturerat, 
    f.UTF8Name as FileName, 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(f.CreateDate) AS 'CreateDate', 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(f.ModifyDate) AS 'ModifyDate', 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(f.AccessDate) AS 'AccessDate'
FROM 
    file f 
    left join path p ON f.pathid = p.pathid
    left join keyword1 k ON f.fileID = k.fileid 
    left join spreadlink s on f.fileID = s.TargetFileID and f.fileID = s.FileID 
WHERE 
    path LIKE '/My/path/to/folder/structure/%' 
    and f.fileid is null
```

Comment: That one didn´t seem to work, it gave me an empty set. I wonder if that was because of the last "and f.fileid is NULL"? f.fileid is never null, all files always have an fileid, but not all files have an row in the spreadlink table. So basically i would like to find all rows from "file" table that does not have an row in "spreadlink".

Comment: I changed it a little bit and i am getting an result this time, but not the same result as with my original query. I am actually not sure which of them gives the correct result. i changed the last where statement to "WHERE 
 (s.fileid is null OR s.TargetFileID IS NULL)
    AND path LIKE '/My/path/to/folder/structure/%';"

Comment: Update, so far i can see that only my original query is giving me the correct result.